# sum of counts of different columns of same table

Tags: sql, count, sum, multiple-columns

Given below table called table

```
+---+---+
| x | y |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

I want to have sql query for the following results

```
+----+-------------+
| id | count_total |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           3 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  5 |           3 |
+----+-------------+
```

Note:
I was able to count separately the rows per id but I could not get the sum for the same id.
so I want to combine or get sum of below queries in a single query.

```
SELECT x, count(*) as total_x FROM table GROUP BY x
SELECT y, count(*) as total_y FROM table GROUP BY y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
A.ID, SUM(A.COUNTS) AS COUNT_TOTAL
FROM
(
SELECT X AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY X
UNION ALL
SELECT Y AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY Y
) A
GROUP BY A.ID
ORDER BY A.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` to bring them together, I did not try it actually but it should work fine. if it did not work please leave a comment and I would be happy to help and edit my answer.

```
select u.x, sum(u.total) 
from 
(
(SELECT x as x, count(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY x) 
union all 
(SELECT y as x, count(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY y)  
) as u 
group by u.x
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @table table
(
x int,
y int
)
insert into @table
select 1,2 union all
select 1,5 union all
select 5,2 union all
select 5,1
select x,SUM(a)  from (
select x,COUNT(*) as a from @table group by x
union all 
select y,COUNT(*) as a from @table group by y
)
a
group by x

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to select all x and all y and then aggregate over them.

```
select id, count(*) as count_total 
from (select x as id from mytable union all select y from mytable) ids
group by id
order by id;
```