# Update field in table with result of select from other table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, count, sql-update, subquery

I have a follow-up question to [sum of counts of different columns of same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876861/sum-of-counts-of-different-columns-of-same-table)
I want to update a field (Z) in another table (B), which also has 'ID' with the results (A.COUNT_TOTAL) of the select query:

```
SELECT A.ID, SUM(A.COUNTS) AS COUNT_TOTAL
FROM
(
SELECT X AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY X
UNION ALL
SELECT Y AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY Y
) A
GROUP BY A.ID
ORDER BY A.ID;`
```

I tried following statement, (but get a vague error message):

```
 UPDATE B
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A.ID, SUM(A.COUNTS) AS COUNT_TOTAL
    FROM
    (
    SELECT X AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Y AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY Y
    ) A
    GROUP BY A.ID) as A on B.ID = A.ID
    SET B.Z = A.COUNT_TOTAL
```

Comment: What vague error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ambiguos (and wrong reference to alias A  .. you are using two times the same name for different alias )
Try using a differnent alias for different subquery eg:

```
  UPDATE B
  INNER JOIN (
  SELECT A.ID, SUM(A.COUNTS) AS COUNT_TOTAL
  FROM
  (
  SELECT X AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY X
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Y AS ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY Y
  ) A
  GROUP BY A.ID)  T on B.ID = T.ID
  SET B.Z = T.COUNT_TOTAL
```